# rfkill list all - It's showing me only bluetooth and nothing about wireless. ,wifi not working, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I'm new here. I'm sorry when I make a mistake. I have just installed UBUNTU 16.04 LTS/

I have problem with Wifi.

I can't  enable wifi in my laptop. I have lenovo G50-70.

`iwconfig`:

```
enp1s0    no wireless extensions.    
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

The output for `sudo lshw -C network`   is:

```
 *-network
 UNCLAIMED
```

network-manager is already the newest version (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2).

It's showing me only bluetooth and nothing about wireless.
`rfkill list all`:

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have Windows 8.1 on this computer too and wifi is working properly.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf line 2: ignoring bad line starting with '“blacklist'
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0621]
    Kernel modules: wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo modprobe wl`:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-39-generic
```

Comment: Done.  I add the output to my question.

Comment: Since you have no rfkill affecting the wireless, why do you blacklist ideapad_something? The file is faulty.

Comment: Do you know how I can repair this file?

Comment: Unless you have any evidence that you actually need it in order for wireless not to be hard blocked in rfkill, I'd suggest that you remove it: `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf ` and reboot. If wireless is not then working, edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-39-generic

Comment: With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible: `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` and reboot.

Comment: I can't.  

E: Failed to get lock / var / lib / dpkg / lock - open (11: Resources temporarily unavailable)
E: The administrative directory could not be blocked (/ var / lib / dpkg /) or would another process use it?

Comment: Is Update Manager or Software Center or Synaptic open? Close them all and try again.

Comment: Configuring Secure Boot ├────────────────────────┐
 │                                                                           │ 
 │ Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.                                   
 │                                                                             
 │ UEFI Secure Boot is not compatible with the use of third-party drivers.     
 │                                                                             
 │ The system will assist you in toggling UEFI Secure Boot. To ensure ...

Comment: what should I do next? close it?

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules/762255#762255 In short, disable Secure Boot in the BIOS.

Comment: Ok. disabled Secure Boot

Comment: Installation finished. No error reported.
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11)...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-39-generic

Comment: May I post an answer for you to accept? Glad it's working.

Comment: Of course. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your readings, we saw a malformed and possibly un-needed .conf file and suggested that you remove it.

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

Next, we found that the needed module was not installed in your currently running kernel and suggested that you re-install it.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Finally, we found that Secure Boot was preventing the loading of the module and suggested that it be disabled in the BIOS.

With these changes, your wireless is working.

Answer (score 0):

Open Additional drivers in Software and updates and see any driver for this. If its there install. 
If its not showing anything. Try to install following package. Open terminal run this command

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo modprobe wl

Reboot once and try.

Comment: Where is driver manager? What is it? I open Software & Updates and there is:

 Broadcom Corporation : BCM43142 802.11b/g/n

The devices is using an alternative driver:
Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA ....

Comment: Configuring Secure Boot  :(